# How to delete specific private IP of from network interface using Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

> > > network_client.network_interfaces.begin_delete((resource_group_name, 'sv-2xfqzx-node2-nic1').ip_configurations[5].private_ip_address
> > > ...

this action is not deleting the private IP from NIC

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a private IP individually, you should remove an IP configuration that contains the private IP that you want to remove. Just try code below:

```
network_interface_name= '<interface name>'
resource_group = '<group name>'
private_ip_to_remove = '<private ip you want to remove>'

nic = network_client.network_interfaces.get(resource_group,network_interface_name)
ip_configs = nic.ip_configurations

for ipcfg in ip_configs:
    print(ipcfg.private_ip_address)
    if ipcfg.private_ip_address == private_ip_to_remove:
        ip_configs.remove(ipcfg)
        print("remove private ip:" + ipcfg.private_ip_address)

network_client.network_interfaces.begin_create_or_update(resource_group,network_interface_name,nic)
```

Result:
[image]

Before:
[image]

After running this script:
[image]